# How to open different links depending on the last selection of my dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am just a beginner in Web development, I mean I don't have much coding knowledge.
I'm stuck in the code regarding how to open different links depending on the last selection of my dynamic form,i.e.,the OS version.
the code is-

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
        var sel, i,
          list = ['mobile', 'laptop'],
          phone = ['Samsung', 'Nokia'],
          laptop = ['HP', 'Dell'],
          android = ['4.1', '4.2'],
          windows = ['8', '8.1'],
          dev_default = '<option value="default" selected>Select your Device brand</option>',
          os_default = '<option value="default" selected>Select your OS version</option>';

        sel_brand = $('#brand');
        sel_version = $('#version');

        $('select').change(function() {
          switch (this.id) {
            case 'main_list':
              $('.secondary').hide();
              sel_brand.find('option').remove();
              sel_brand.append(dev_default);
              sel_brand.show();
              if (this.value == 'mobile') {
                for (i = 0; i < phone.length; i++) {
                  $("#brand").append(
                    '<option value="' + phone[i] + '">' + phone[i] + '</option>'
                  );
                }
              } else if (this.value == 'laptop') {
                for (i = 0; i < phone.length; i++) {
                  $("#brand").append(
                    '<option value="' + laptop[i] + '">' + laptop[i] + '</option>'
                  );
                }
              }
              break;
            case 'brand':
              sel_version.find('option').remove();
              sel_version.append(os_default);
              sel_version.show();
              if (this.value == 'Samsung') {
                for (i = 0; i < android.length; i++) {
                  $("#version").append(
                    '<option value="' + android[i] + '">' + android[i] + '</option>'
                  );
                }
              } else if (this.value == 'Nokia' || this.value == 'HP' || this.value == 'Dell') {
                for (i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
                  $("#version").append(
                    '<option value="' + windows[i] + '">' + windows[i] + '</option>'
                  );
                }
              }
              break;
          }
        });

      }); //END document.ready()</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css"> .secondary {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<select id="main_list">
  <option value="default" selected>Select Your List</option>
  <option value="mobile">mobile list</option>
  <option value="laptop">laptop list</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="brand" class="secondary"></select>
<br />
<select id="version" class="secondary"></select>
<br />
```